# How should an array of strings be formatted in a REST API call?

Tags: arrays, rest, julia, http-post

I am working on calling this REST API on Deviant Art. It is described [here](https://www.deviantart.com/developers/console/stash/stash_submit/0f1832daa6b58a05841ec6058520c4f3?validate_token=ac1ec7516f580cfbc829&validate_key=1706356107&title=Smallish&artist_comments=Cool%20image%20I%20made&tags%5B%5D=black&tags%5B%5D=hot&tags%5B%5D=busty&tags%5B%5D=cute&original_url=&is_dirty=false&file=2062810105216536&itemid=&stack=&stackid=&da_version=&mature_content=false&endpoint=%2Fstash%2Fsubmit). I am not very familiar with REST APIs so this may be a dumb question, but I cannot figure out how I write an array of strings in such a call.

At first I tried:

```
item1, item2, item3
```

But that didn't seem to work so I did:

```
["item1", "item2", "item3"]
```

Didn't work either. The description of the rest API is found below. I am trying to provide elements to `tags`.

> POST, GET artist_comments (string) :
> optional
> Additional information about the submission provided by the author
>
> POST, GET tags (array[string]) :
> optional
> An array of tags describing the submission. Letters, numbers and underscore only.
> min: 1

I am using Julia programming language for this, but I guess the problem is universal. Here is an excerpt of what I do. In this example I am turning the params.tags into a text string. In the original version I just passed the array directly, but that didn't work.

```
headers = []
data = convert_to_dict(params)
data["attachment"] = io
data["access_token"] = token.access_token

quoted_tags = map(tag->"\"$tag\"", params.tags)
tags_str = "[" * join(quoted_tags, ",") * "]"

data["tags"] = tags_str
body = HTTP.Form(data)
resp = HTTP.post(url, headers, body)
body = HTTP.payload(resp)
```

If you don't know the answer to this question, perhaps you can give me some hint at HOW to debug this or go about finding out how it is supposed to look.

Answer (score 0):

I struggled to figure this out but it was actually Codepilot in VS Code which gave me the answer. Since AI answers aren't allowed I will write its answer using my own words.

As far as I can understand there is not one single convention for how to pass array data. Rather there are number of styles. So if `tags` is the key it could be set as:

1. tags=tag1,tag2,tag3
2. tags=["tag1","tag2","tag3"]
3. tags[0]=tag1&tags[1]=tag2&tags[2]=tag3

So to get this to work in Julia I wrote the following code:

```
tags_dict = Dict("tags[$(i-1)]" => tag for (i, tag) in enumerate(params.tags))
data = merge(data, tags_dict)
delete!(data, "tags")
```